# Changing InnoDB pool size without impacting the local server - MySQL windows

Tags: mysql, windows, innodb

Firstly, I have tried looking for various solutions to the issue I am describing below but nothing really worked hence I am posting my own question.

My issue began with trying to modify the datatype of a column in a table with ~9,5 mil rows.
I got the 1206 error code and after a quick search understood I need to change the pool size in the settings files and did it in the my.ini file (changed from 8 to 64 MB).
After restarting my PC the workbench couldn't connect as the local server stopped running.
When I tried to restart the server via services it kept stopping all the time.

After I switched the my.ini file to the old and original version and restarting the PC the workbench is working and the server is running but my original problem continues.

Your help and advice will be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Michael

Comment: Which version of MySQL?  Even 64M is pathetically tiny; how much RAM do you have?

Comment: @RickJames The version is 8.0.17 and the RAM is 16GB.

Answer (score 0):

On a 16GB machine, you should probably set `innodb_buffer_pool_size` to `11G`:

```
SET GLOBAL innodb_buffer_pool_size = 11G;
```

Also change the setting in my.cnf.